# Deploy API Gateway from Command Line

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying for two days to deploy a POST Rest API, which would be the trigger for an already existing Lambda function on AWS, through a bash script using the `aws-cli`. The thing is that I am able to upload and deploy the API but it doesn't work. I tested my Lambda fuction through the test feature on AWS itself and it works. But when I call the API it returns this as header

```json
{"x-amzn-ErrorType":"InternalServerErrorException"}
```

and this as body

```json
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

and this is the log I find on API Gateway test functionality

```
Execution log for request ba8d70b6-bb5e-49c5-9ff4-7927983c51d8
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Starting execution for request: ba8d70b6-bb5e-49c5-9ff4-7927983c51d8
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /provoletta
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Method request path: {}
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Method request query string: {}
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: {
    "device": {
        "uuid": "4",
        "lastPosition": "4",
        "lastSeen": "4",
        "raspberryId": "4",
        "roomNumber": "34"
    }
}
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:provoletta/invocations
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=ba8d70b6-bb5e-49c5-9ff4-7927983c51d8, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************53a5a7, X-Amz-Date=20201126T164155Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=eca0u6a3ed, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:***:eca0u6a3ed/test-invoke-stage/POST/provoletta, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_eca0u6a3ed, X-Amz-Security-Token=*** [TRUNCATED]
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
    "device": {
        "uuid": "4",
        "lastPosition": "4",
        "lastSeen": "4",
        "raspberryId": "4",
        "roomNumber": "34"
    }
}
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:provoletta/invocations
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
Thu Nov 26 16:41:55 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 500
```

This is how I am trying to create and build the API through bash script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
api_id=$(aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'provoletta' --query 'id' --output text)
resource_id=$(aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id $api_id --query 'items' --output text)
resource_id=${resource_id::-2}
result_id=$(aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id $api_id --parent-id $resource_id --path-part provoletta --query 'id' --output text)

aws apigateway put-method \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --authorization-type "NONE"

aws apigateway put-method-response \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \ 
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --status-code 200

aws apigateway put-integration \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --type AWS \
    --integration-http-method POST \
    --uri arn:aws:apigateway:$AWS_REGION:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:$AWS_REGION:$ACCOUNT_ID:function:provoletta/invocations \
    --request-templates '{"application/x-www-form-urlencoded":"{\"body\": $input.json(\"$\")}"}'

aws apigateway put-integration-response \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --status-code 200 \
    --selection-pattern ""

aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $api_id --stage-name provoletta
```

If I create an API for the same Lambda function on API Gateway console itself it works without problems. So, what's the problem with this script?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission problem. Specifically, it looks like you did not give permission for the API Gateway to invoke your Lambda function:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function.

To fix this you should "add permissions" to your Lambda as described in the [AWS CLI documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html).

Based on your "code", this might already do the trick, assuming your Lambda function is called `provoletta`:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --function-name provoletta \
    --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
    --statement-id AllowGatewayToInvokeFunction \
    --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thank you! I added this piece and now the error changed, I will post it in another answer, but at least my function runs because it adds data to a DynamoDB table!

Comment: Please do not change your question like this after you get a working answer. Now there is an answer that does not answer your question. It is confusing for others. Accept the answer and please create a new question.

Comment: I sincerely apologize. By the way, your previous answer helped a lot and I really thank you for that, but it didn't completely solve the problem because it still returns me an error. Anyway, I will follow your advice and create a new question. Thank you again.